# Cannot access expected class constructor parameters in kotlin multi-platform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I'm currently working on a multi-platform module using kotlin. To do so, I rely on the [`expect`/`actual` mechanism](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html).

I declare a simple class in `Common.kt`:

```
expect class Bar constructor(
    name: String
)
```

I'd like to use the defined class in a common method (also present in `Common.kt`):

```
fun hello(bar: Bar) {
    print("Hello, my name is ${bar.name}")
}
```

The actual implementation is defined in `Jvm.kt`:

```
actual data class Bar actual constructor(
    val name: String    
)
```

The problem is I got the following error inside my `hello` function

> Unresolved reference: name

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove `constructor` from expect class.

Comment: At least, try it on your machine before "suggesting" something

Answer (score 4):

> Expected classes constructor cannot have a property parameter

Therefore it is necessary to describe the property as a class member with `val name: String`

> Actual constructor of 'Bar' has no corresponding expected declaration

However, for the actual constructor to match the expected declaration the number of parameters has to be the same. That is why the **parameter** is also added `name: String` in the constructor in addition to the existence of the **property**.

```
expect class Bar(name: String) {
    val name: String
}

actual class Bar actual constructor(actual val name: String)
```

Note: *If we leave the constructor empty of the expected class we see how the IDE complains when adding a constructor in the current class for the incompatibility.*

GL

Answer (score 0):

It should be `val name` in the `expect` part as well, either in the constructor parameter list or as a member property.

Comment: If I do so I get `Expected class constructor cannot have a property parameter`.

Comment: Then add a member property as the second part says. The actual class should still be able to implement it as a property constructor parameter.

Comment: If I do so I cannot instantiate the class: `Expected class Bar does not have a default constructor`.

Comment: Which line gives this error? I don't see why a default constructor would be needed.